# Conditional w/Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, if-statement, conditional-statements

Need a help with conditionals for pandas dataframe. Apologies in advance for the basic question or if it's covered elsewhere.

Here's the example dataframe:

```
employee sales revenue salary
12345    20    10000   100000
```

I have a few conditions based on data which will result in salary changing.

scenarios:
if sales >10 and revenue > $5,000, increase salary by 20%
if sales <5 and revenue > $5,000, increase salary by 10%
otherwise, do nothing.

```
variables:
high_sales = 10
low_sales = 5
high_revenue = 5000
big_increase = 1.2
small_increase = 1.1
```

I know this requires some nesting but it's not clear to me how to do it.

I want the outcome to be a dataframe with only the salary column adjusted.

Here's the code:

```
df['salary'] = np.where((df['sales']>=high_sales & df['revenue'] 
>=high_revenue), df['salary'] * big_increase, (df['sales']<=low_sales & 
df['revenue'] >=high_revenue), df['salary'] * small_increase, df['sales'])
```

Is this right?

Comment: That's why I shouldn't try editing formatting from my phone. Sorry for messing it up. Please take "here's  the code" out of the bottom code block to fix the string highlighting.

Answer (score 1):

With multiple conditions, it's nicer to use [`np.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) rather than `np.where`:

```
conds = [(df.sales > 10) & (df.revenue > 5000),
         (df.sales < 5) & (df.revenue > 5000)]

choices = [df.salary * 1.2, df.salary * 1.1]

df['salary'] = np.select(conds, choices, default = df.revenue)
```

Comment: Better, in my opinion: `df['salary'] *= np.select(conds, [1.2, 1.1], 1)`.

Comment: Yeah, perhaps that is a bit nicer, thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: Thanks all. What does the "default = df.revenue" part do?

Comment: That's for the *otherwise, do nothing* condition that you had in your post. You can take a look at the default argument in the documentation I linked